# is the U.S. really in such bad shape?

Tags: election, primaries

The very premise of this election primary season seems to be that the U.S. is in really bad shape.  There seems to be a sense that there should be no government, because the government is to blame for everything that is wrong in this country.  Yet, it seems that the recovery from the 2008-09 recession has gone well, unemployment is down again, and the economy is healthy.  Where does the widespread perception that government is to blame for everything come from - this is the sentiment that Trump and some other republican candidates seem to be riding on.  From my perspective, it seems that John Kasich is the only serious candidate that can make a difference to the future of the country - he seems rational and level-headed.  But he has virtually no traction.  What is ailing America?  Do we really need a sea change that brings a vitriolic demagogue like Trump to the presidency, so all his hate-speech can be turned into policies and that is what will return America to its greatness?

Comment: There are issues with the premise of your question. Unemployment is down, because a record number of individuals have left the job market and stopped looking for work. People aren't arguing for no government, but less government, following the unconstitutional overreach of the EPA, put into check by court action, the federal interference of Common Core, and the overall expansion of unelected bureaucratic regulatory control.

Comment: @DrunkCynic there's also issues with your premise as well...which is kind of what the OP is referring too...candidates leverage these misunderstandings to make things look much more dire than they actually are.

Answer (score 3):

> The very premise of this election primary season seems to be that the U.S. is in really bad shape

That tends to be the premise of every election season in the US. Paint a picture of the nation falling apart, then offer up your 'plan' to make things great again. It's political marketing. It's rarely as bad as they say it is.

Semi-related would be to see how 'truthful' some of the politicians are. Note that some of them painting the most dire picture aren't necessarily known for knowing the entire set of facts:

[image]

(Image from the [NYTimes](http://www.nytimes.com/2015/12/13/opinion/campaign-stops/all-politicians-lie-some-lie-more-than-others.html))

Comment: Presenting an informational graphic depicting the judgments of PolitiFact, but omitting the persisting controversy pertaining to PolitiFact bias, has an interesting parallel to the efforts of political marketing.

Comment: @DrunkCynic going along with the theme of this question, controversy towards politifact is often contrived. They've been accused of being biased from all sides of the political spectrum. They are also not backed by any particular "think tank".  I'd say they tend to be the more respectable of sources.

Comment: Regardless, pointing out that Carson and Trump tend to be the two that tend to just say whatever is on their mind regardless of reality is hardly biased. That's pretty much common sense at this point. :)